# How to kill a subprocess initiated by a different function in the same class

Tags: python, subprocess, daemon

I want to kill a process from another function in the class attending to the fact that it was initiated by another function. Here's an example:

```
 import time

 class foo_class:
    global foo_global
    def foo_start(self):
        import subprocess
        self.foo_global =subprocess.Popen(['a daemon service'])

    def foo_stop(self):
        self.foo_start.foo_global.kill()
        self.foo_start.foo_global.wait()


foo_class().foo_start()
time.sleep(5)
foo_class().foo_stop()
```

How should I define foo_stop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jterrace code works. If you don't want it to start when you initialize, just call Popen in a separate function and pass nothing to the init function

```
import subprocess 
import time

class foo_class(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def start(self):
        self.foo = subprocess.Popen(['a daemon service'])

    def stop(self):
        self.foo.kill()
        self.foo.wait() #don't know if this is necessary?

    def restart(self):
        self.start()


foo = foo_class()
foo.start()
time.sleep(5)
foo.stop()
```

Comment: AWESOME! Thanks.
Thanks also to everyone who has answered

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you want something like this:

```
import subprocess 
import time

class foo_class(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = None

    def start(self):
        self.stop()
        self.foo = subprocess.Popen(['a daemon service'])
        self.foo.start()

    def stop(self):
        if self.foo:
            self.foo.kill()
            self.foo.wait()
            self.foo = None


foo = foo_class()
foo.start()
time.sleep(5)
foo.stop()
```

Some things I've changed:

- Imports should generally go at the top of the file.
- Classes should inherit from `object`.
- You want to use an [instance variable](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references).
- It doesn't make much sense for your class's method names to start with the class name.
- You were creating a **new instance** of `foo_class` when calling its methods. Instead, you want to create a single instance and calls the methods on it.

Comment: Thanks jterrace but not exactly. I want to start the service with the start function and kill it with the stop function. That way I would initiate the process at the class __init__ and I don't want to do that (the class has loads of more functions).

Comment: why don't you add a .wait() method to the init class so its self.foo = subproces.Popen(['a daemon']).wait()   That way you won't start until you explicitly call that method

Comment: Sure, easy fix, modified to only create the process when started.